# MySQL - Table is full

Tags: mysql

Quando eu tento fazer o upload de um arquivo para uma tabela do meu banco mysql o sistema retorna o erro Table is Full. Todavia, tenho outras tabelas maiores e mais pesadas que essa tabela que não apresentam esse erro. A tabela do erro tem, aproximadamente, 300MB. Já setei a variavel  innodb_file_per_table = 1

Mas não consegui setar `innodb_data_file_path` no `my.cnf` pois toda vez que eu setava a variável o mysql service não iniciava, apesar de eu apenas adicionar as linhas:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_data_file_path = 'ibdata1:10G:autoextend'
```

Já tentei este outro método apresentado [aqui](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/000796.html) com o ALTER TABLE mas também não funcionou. Verifiquei o espaço em disco através do comando `df -h` e, todas as partições estão com bastante espaço livre. Não sei mais o que poderia ser.

Adicionando o código mencionado no comentário do Raylan resultou num erro de inicialização do mysql, então eu corrigi meu `my.cnf` para:

```
[innodb]
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10G:autoextend:max:10G
```

E mesmo assim o erro do **Table is full** persiste.

Digitando o código `mysql` no servidor aparece `unknown variable 'innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10G:autoextend:max:10G'`

Numa outra tentativa realizei um DROP TABLE e mesmo agora com a tabela vazia o erro continua. Não sei mais por onde prosseguir.

O comando para criar a tabela foi:

```
    CREATE TABLE auxiliar_MA.HT_MA4_SBX_SEG
    (
      TS_SAMPLETM  DATETIME
    , VL_M4000109 DOUBLE
    , VL_M4000110 DOUBLE
    , VL_M4000111 DOUBLE
   ...
    , VL_M4000669 DOUBLE
    , VL_M4000674 DOUBLE
    , VL_M4000675 DOUBLE
    , VL_M4000676 DOUBLE
    )
    ;
```

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Se por o "max" não rola? innodb_data_file_path = 'ibdata1:10G:autoextend:max:10G'

Comment: Sei que não tem haver com o problema, mas acho que upar arquivos direto dentro de banco é uma péssima pratica. Tem um link aqui falando sobre isso e os motivos, assim que achar posto como comentário, porque é apenas uma dica e não uma resposta ao problema.

Comment: Adicionei o códino no my.cnf e resultou no erro que adicionei na pergunta. Quanto ao upload do arquivo, acabei me expressando mal. Estou usando um software de ETL para ler arquivos txt e fazer upload dos dados no banco de dados.

Comment: Acho que o comentário do @GuilhermeNascimento é relvante, e _tem_ a ver com o problema sim. O banco não foi desenhado para ter um monte de arquivos dentro - a melhor coisa é você refatorar o sistema para ter apenas nomes e caminhos de arquivo no banco e guarda-los no filesystem.

Comment: Mas não existem arquivos no banco, apenas dados. A minha rotina de tratamento de dados lê os arquivos .txt e faz o upload apenas dos dados para o banco.

Comment: ok - então, dei uma olhada na docuemtnação  e não achei pista - (a nao er que sua versão do Mysql seja muito antiga, de antes de 2012). O erro só deveria ocorrer se o disco estiver cheio.

Comment: está complicado hehehe como eu editei ali, mesmo com a tabela com 0bytes ele acusa Table is Full; enquanto que, em outras tabelas, consigo fazer a inserção de dados sem problemas.

Comment: pode colocar o comando "create table" usado?

Comment: Adicionei, acredito que não tenha nada de estranho nele